# Python 2.7.14: "+=1 to Dictionary Item if Key Exists Else = 1" Syntax Doesn't Work

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to +=1 to an item in a dictionary if it exists, else create the key in the dictionary and set it to 1. I know I can use more than one line of logic for this, but I really want to see if its possible to keep the logic on one line. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
myDict = {}
myDict[100] += 1 if 100 in myDict else 1
```

It throw KeyError though if the key 100 doesn't exist. How can I set the one lined else logic to set key 100 to 1? Is it even possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that this is parsed as

```
myDict[100] += (1 if 100 in myDict else 1)
```

which is just the same as writing

```
myDict[100] += 1
```

and of course that requires `myDict[100]` already to exist.  You can instead use a regular assignment and the dictionary `get` method, which lets you specify what is to be returned if the key is not already there:

```
myDict[100] = myDict.get(100, 0) + 1
```

Or you can use `collections.Counter`, which is a special-purpose dictionary designed for exactly this job:

```
import collections
myDict = collections.Counter()
myDict[100] += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [get](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict[100] =  my_dict.get(100, 0) +  1
```

**Output**

```
{100: 1}
```

**Explanation** *(from the documentation)*

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing already in the value so the error is thrown if is not in the dict
This would work

```
if 100 in mydict:
    mydict[100] += 1
else:
    mydict[100] = 1
```

However even prettier would be
`mydict[100] = mydict.get(100, 0) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to collections.Counter there is collections.defaultdict, which allows you to set a default value to be used when a non-initialized key is passed to the dict. It is overkill for counters of course, but can be really wonderful in other situations.

Answer (score -1):

```
myDict[100] = myDict[100]+1 if 100 in myDict else 1
```

or, maybe better:

```
myDict.setdefault(100, 0)
myDict[100] +=1
```